# Java Applets don't seem to work on my Windows 8 laptop

Tags: windows-8, java

I have a new Windows 8 laptop and I went to a page that requires Java because it contains a Java Applet. I downloaded and installed Java and restarted the browser but it still does not work.

I get a `ClassNotFoundException` and this is true of other sites that require Java too.

Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: What version of java do you have installed?  Do you have the 32-bit and 64-bit installation installed?  Install the current version from the following location: http://java.com/en/download/manual.jsp and try the application again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you installed latest java.

Please make sure that java is working fine in your browser by visiting [this website.](http://www.java.com/en/download/installed.jsp)
Also make sure that same website/applet works on other browsers in your computer. If not please check you have java enabled in your browser.

To check whether java is enabled or not in your browser - follow [this link](http://java.com/en/download/help/enable_browser.xml)

Answer (score 0):

I am too learning java and trying to get applets running.
I also use windows 8 and get the ClassNotFoundException.

A couple of things to check:

1. Use the `<object>` tag instead of the `<applet>` tag because the `<applet>` tag was deprecated in HTML 4 and removed in HTML5.
2. I'm not sure exactly how the tag is meant to be structured but make sure that's ok because it may have changed with the `<object>` tag.